# Why is my output shifted after I listened for input?

Tags: c, terminator

I figured out that this isn't problem with my terminal, because it does happen in vscode terminal as well. (I'm complete new to c and I don't really know where the problem is)

```
0000010000000000000000000
                     0000000000000000000000000
 0000000000000000000000000
                          0000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000
                               0000000000000000000000000
           0000000000000000000000000
                                    0000000000000000000000000
                0000000000000000000000000
                                        0000000000000000000000000
```

It is two dimensional array of zeros and one one

This is my code until I run into that infinite loop it shifts but until that it works normally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
int rows, colls;
rows = 10;
colls = 25;
int dysplay[rows][colls];
int grid[rows][colls];
int marked[rows*colls];
int x_axis, y_axis;
x_axis = 0;
y_axis = 0;
srand(time(0));

//setting grid of mines and 
for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < colls; j++)
    {
        //get random nuber betwene 1 and 0
        int num = rand() % 2;
        //give the coordinates value of random number
        grid[i][j] = num;
        dysplay[i][j] = 0; 
        //print numbers
        printf("%d", num);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

while (1)
{
    initscr();              // Initialize ncurses
    cbreak();              // Disable line buffering and character echoing
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);  // Enable keypad function keys (e.g., function keys, arrow keys)
    noecho();              // Disable character echoing
    refresh();             // Refresh the screen

    char con = getch();      // Wait for a keypress
    if (con == 'd')
    {
        x_axis = x_axis + 1;
        dysplay[y_axis][x_axis] = 1;
        dysplay[y_axis][x_axis-1] = 0;
    }
    system("clear");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < colls; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", dysplay[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

I compile it like this

```
gcc ./main.c -o ./main -Wall -Wextra -g3 -lncurses
```

Comment: If you're using ncurses, why not use it all the way? Replace the `printf` calls with the ncurses variants `printw` (and its variants). Don't do `system("clear");`, that won't play nice with ncurses. Please read some documentation about ncurses, and some beginners tutorials.

Comment: Oh, and one *very* important thing: Do all your setup (like `initscr()` etc.) ***once***, at the start of the program. A decent beginners guide or tutorial should help a lot.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude printw solves the shift, but when I press any button it moves everything down accept first line and after 7 presses it dispapiers.